# How to limit the checkbox selection both columnwise and rowwise in gridview in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridview

I am having an grid view with check box that have 5 row and 6 column.what is my requirement is i can select row wise 3 check box and in the whole grid i can select totally 6 check box at an time.I have tried these below code but Its not working

```
    function IdExists(elements, id) {
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            if (elements[i].id.indexOf(id) > -1) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    function Check_Click(chkBx) {
        var c = 0;
        Parent = document.getElementById('<% =Gv1.ClientID %>');          
        for (i = 0; i < Parent.rows.length; i++) {
            if (items[i].checked) {
                c = c + 1;
            }

            var row = Parent.rows[i];
            var items = row.getElementsByTagName('input');

            if (items.length > 0) {
                if (IdExists(items, chkBx.id)) {
                    var tot = 0,cc=0;

                    for (j = 0; j < items.length; j++)
                    {

                        if (items[j].type == 'checkbox' && items[j].checked && items[j].disabled == false)
                        {

                            tot = tot + 1;
                            if ((tot > 3)&&(c>0))
                            {
                                alert('Cannot take more than 3 hours');
                                chkBx.checked = false;
                                return;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }



    }
</script>
```

Comment: Any error that you receive here ?

Comment: Not getting any error.Its checking row wise alone i.e Its  showing pop-up if i click continuous 3 checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery you can achieve the result with lesser code. Just give all the checkboxes a CssClass, say, `mycheckbox`

```
$(".mycheckbox").on("click", function(){
    var elm = this, $elm = $(elm);
    if(elm.checked){
        var totalCheckedBoxes = $(".mycheckbox:checked").length;
        var rowWiseCheckedBoxes = $elm.closest('tr').find(".mycheckbox:checked").length;
        if(totalCheckedBoxes === 6 || rowWiseCheckedBoxes === 3){
            elm.checked = false;
            if(totalCheckedBoxes === 6){
                alert("Cannot select more than 6");
            }
            else{
                alert("Cannot take more than 3 hours");
            }
        }
    }
});
```